# Make Tab Content Height Consistent Across All Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TabHost setup with two tabs.  The height of the tab content area expands and collapses when switching between tabs to match the data displayed within it.  I'm trying to figure out how to make the height consistent so that tab1 is as tall as it needs to be and tab2 uses that same height.

The height of the TabHost is controlled programmatically to make sure it doesn't exceed 70% of the screen height.  Tab1 contains a ScrollView so its data can be scrolled if need be.

TabHost layout:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TabWidget
      android:id="@android:id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/traffic_map_bubble_padding_top"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/traffic_map_bubble_padding_right"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/traffic_map_bubble_padding_bottom"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/traffic_map_bubble_padding_left"
      android:background="@drawable/map_ballon_bg_selector"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Tab1 Layout

```
<ScrollView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/traffic_restriction_tab_1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/traffic_restriction_location_1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/traffic_restriction_bg"
      android:gravity="center"
      style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_style"
      android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TableLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/traffic_map_bubble_table_margin_top"
      android:shrinkColumns="2">
        <TableRow>
          <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_label_style"
            android:text="@string/label_dates"/>
          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/traffic_restriction_date_range"
            android:layout_column="2"
            style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_style"/>
          </TableRow>

  <TableRow>
    <TextView
      android:layout_column="1"
      style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_label_style"
      android:text="@string/label_impact"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/traffic_restriction_type"
      android:layout_column="2"
      style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_style"/>
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow>
    <TextView
      android:layout_column="1"
      style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_label_style"
      android:text="@string/label_condition"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/traffic_restriction_detail"
      android:layout_column="2"
      style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_style"/>
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/traffic_restriction_press_release_row"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/traffic_map_bubble_table_double_space">

    <TextView
      android:layout_column="1"
      android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/traffic_restriction_press_release"
      android:layout_column="2"
      style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_style"/>
  </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Tab2 Layout

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/traffic_restriction_tab_2"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/traffic_restriction_location_2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/traffic_restriction_bg"
android:gravity="center"
style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_style"
android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/traffic_map_bubble_table_margin_top"
android:shrinkColumns="2">

<TableRow>
  <TextView
    android:layout_column="1"
    style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_label_style"
    android:text="@string/label_email"/>

  <TextView
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:autoLink="email"
    style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_style"
    android:text="@string/email_public_relations"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/traffic_map_bubble_table_double_space">

  <TextView
    android:layout_column="1"
    style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_label_style"
    android:text="@string/label_phone_instate"/>

  <TextView
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_style"
    android:text="@string/phone_public_relations_instate"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/traffic_map_bubble_table_double_space">

  <TextView
    android:layout_column="1"
    style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_label_style"
    android:text="@string/label_phone"/>

  <TextView
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    style="@style/traffic_map_bubble_style"
    android:text="@string/phone_public_relations"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```